# Application to track installed versions of modules for about 100 clients

Tags: open-source, web-apps, version-control

I'm looking for a web application where I can choose a client out of 100 clients and then I can see the following information:

Which modules does this client have (up to 20) including the version of each module.

Adding a module and updating the version information should be simple.

I thought of writing it by myself in Python, but there surely already exists some cool tool for it?

Comment: Hi. You probably need to add more information type of client, operating system, what kind of modules  etc. All assumed all run from web or intranet?

Comment: I now wrote my own application in Flask (it's a quite specific use case), running in Kubernetes.